# Information retrieval system

Tags: information-retrieval

What is the difference between TF-IDF ranking of documents and binary independence model of ranking? I'm unable to differentiate them.

I think practical implementation of binary independence model leads to have TF-IDF. Please help me if i'm wrong.

Comment: you're right... tf-idf is ad-hoc... the probabilistic analysis establishes why a function like tf-idf should work well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that in Binary Independence Model there is no idea about how important a word is, and all words are treated same. But weighting words with TF-IDF will give better scores to words that are used more in one document and have less document frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The [Binary Independence Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Independence_Model) assumption is that documents are binary vectors. That is, only the presence or absence of terms in documents are recorded. On the other hand, according to [Vector Space Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model), documents are represented by a vector of term weights and TF-IDF is just one way to represent the term weights.